# Crear combobox y textbox a partir de un botón en VBA ACCESS

Tags: vba, botón, ms-access, combobox, textbox

### ¿Cómo puedo crear controles dentro de un formulario activo, utilizando VBA?

Buenas a todos.
Tengo un formulario en ACCESS para manejar la entrada de datos de "ESTUDIOS" con diferentes ubicaciones geográficas. Estoy utilizando dos 'controles':
El primero es un **combobox** *[Estado]* y el otro es un **campo de texto** *[Municipio]*.

Lo que quiero es tener un **botón** *[Agregar Ubicación]* que cuando se clickee, genere una copia de estos dos controles justo debajo de los primeros; de esta manera busco hacer más dinámica la generación de ubicaciones dentro de un mismo "ESTUDIO" para los usuarios, sin tener que interactuar con la *vista Diseño*. El problema es que me parece que ACCESS no permite realizar algo de este estilo.
Intenté con la propiedad **CreateControl** pero me dice que no es posible generarlo a menos que se esté en la vista diseño; debido a esto intenté pasar a la vista diseño, generar los controles y posteriormente volver a la vista Formulario pero tampoco me funciona.

```
Esto es lo que he intentado:

Private Sub AgregarUbicacion_Click()

  CreateControl "Formulario", acComboBox, acDetail,,,,,,10

  //Dejo la mayoría de los valores en blanco porque sólo hacen referencia a las dimensiones
  //y coordenadas

End Sub
```

Debido a que me arrojó el mensaje "Debe estar en la Vista Diseño o Presentación para crear o eliminar controles."

```
Intenté:

Private Sub AgregarUbicacion_Click()

   Formulario.SetFocus
   RunCommand (acCmdDesignView) //Para entrar primero a la vista diseño

   CreateControl "altearCotizaciones2", acComboBox, acDetail, , , , , , 10
                                //Generar el combobox    

   RunCommand (acCmdFormView)   //Volver a la vista formulario

End Sub
```

### esto último me arrojó el mensaje: "Microsoft Access no puede agregar, cambiar el nombre o eliminar los controles solicitados." Aún así creo que esta solución (de andar cambiando de vistas para generar o destruir controles es muy ineficiente y se verá reflejado en más problemas posteriores por lo que quisiera saber si alguno ha pasado por problemas de este estilo y cómo es posible solucionarlo.

Para dar una mejor visualización de lo que deseo hacer y contestando al apoyo de @Elier Sánchez, dejo las siguientes imágenes:

[image: Lo que tengo]
Esto es lo que tengo, un pequeño formulario que pide esos datos. Quiero enfocarme en los últimos 3 controles. 2 Combobox y un Textbox: "Estado, Municipio e Indicaciones"

[image: Lo que deseo antes de dar click]
Quiero tener un botón "Agregar estado" que cuando se de click me "duplique" estos 3 controles como sigue en la imagen:

[image: Lo que deseo suceda al dar click]
Cada vez que se clickee ese botón rojo, se agregarán nuevos controles para llenar las ubicaciones correspondientes. El botón "Quitar Estado" sería algo extra posterior para quitar dichos controles en caso de no necesitarlos.

Gracias por leer y responder.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Perdona, pero no entiendo bien lo que quieres conseguir. ¿Podrías poner unas capturas de pantalla enseñando desde donde partes y a dónde quieres llegar?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes he agregado las imágenes solicitadas. Espero quede más claro. En caso de no serlo, por favor dímelo

Comment: Vale, ahora que veo tus pantallazos, ¿puede ser que desees asociar a una misma empresa varios estados/Municipios/Indicaciones?

Comment: Así es. Justamente eso quiero pero de forma dinámica porque no siempre serán 2 estados, ó 3, ó 1, sino que quiero que varíe a gusto del usuario.

Comment: Vale, en ese caso, tienes que crear, por un lado, una tabla de empresas, y otra tabla donde iran los estados/Municipios/Indicaciones asociados a empresas de la rpimera tabla. Luego, sería un formulario principal basado en la tabla de empresas, y meter un subformulario con diseño *formularios continuos* asociado a la segunda tabla. Como tú lo quieres hacer, no es viable, porque son cambios de diseño en bruto de 1 único formulario.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que los municipios y estados no están ligados a cierta empresa sino que son independientes y pueden variar indefinidamente por lo que la solución de generar dos tablas vinculadas que incluya un determinado número de estados, no es una solución.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, pero en algún sitio tiene que estar la información si te la quieres llevar a un formulario. En alguna tabla se tendrá que reflejar los municipios y estados. Entiendo perfectamente que los estados y municipios sean independientes, y no sean un número determinado, pero si no ¿Cómo guardas la información? Por eso digo lo de una tabla que te permita crear infinitos registros, de empresas y estados/municipios.

Comment: Porque lo que haría sería generar un sólo campo que concatenara todos los que se han agregado y ese sería el que se daría de alta realmente. Entonces en conclusión: NO SE PUEDE HACER actualmente en ACCESS de Office 365